# Cannot install WordPress ($_POST is empty)

Tags: installation, ftp, php, wordpress

I am trying to install WordPress on my site under http://example.com/blog. What I did so far is:

1. Download and unzip the most recent version of WordPress
2. Upload the contents of the wordpress folder to my site's blog folder using FTP
3. Edited wp-config.php to contain all of the required information (database info and secret keys)

I had initially tried to create the config file using the automated process, but I got the error `table prefix cannot be empty`. However, on the next step (where you give the blog's name and create the admin account) I am getting the `must use valid username` error. I know I am using a valid username because it is exactly like my username for this site.

To debug I decided to `var_dump` the `$_POST` variable. It showed an empty array. This explains why I had to manually create my config file. I got the table prefix error because that is the installation script's first error check...

Any ideas on what I can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welp, I figured it out.

I remembered that I had a problem with post data a while back and the reason was that in my main site's .htaccess I have a rule that redirects pages to their no-ending counterpart (i.e. `install.php` to `install`). This redirect causes post data to be lost, so all I had to do was change the `install.php` reference (exact line was `install.php?step=2`) to `install?step=2`.

I assume that if I had found the spot for the first step (where you set up the database access) and changed the reference there too, that part would also have worked.